# PHP Regex replace is not producing the desired result

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm creating a dictionary application in PHP and MariaDB, and trying to simulate some basic markdown. When I have a definition like this:

```
This is an example definition. Here is a link to [foo]. This is an [aliased link|bar].
```

Then `[foo]` will be translated into a link to the 'foo' definition page, and `[aliased link|bar]` will translate into a link to the 'bar' definition page. If there's a pipe then whatever's before the pipe (|) will become the link text, and after the pipe becomes the link destination. If there's no pipe, then the expression in brackets becomes the link text and destination.

So I would translate this to the following HTML:

```
This is an example definition. Here is a link to <a href="foo">foo</a>. This is an <a href="bar">aliased link</a>.
```

The easiest way I could think of to do this was through two regex replaces. So let's say my example string is called `$def`, here is the code I've tried to make these replacements:

```
$pattern1 = '/\[(.*?)?\]/m';
$replace1 = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
$def = preg_replace($pattern1, $replace1, $def);

$pattern2 = '/\[([^]]*?)(?:\|([^]]*?))\]/m';
$replace2 = '<a href="$2">$1</a>';
$def = preg_replace($pattern2, $replace2, $def);
```

(I assumed it would be easier to do it using two regexes, but if there's a simpler one-regex solution I'd love to know.)

However, I've clearly got something wrong with the regex, as this is what happens when I echo `$def` (the links are just illustrative for now, the destination isn't important):

> This is an example definition. Here is a link to [foo](http://google.com). This is an aliased [link|bar](http://google.com).

And the HTML:

```
"This is an example definition. Here is a link to "
<a href="foo">foo</a>
". This is an" 
<a href="aliased link|bar">aliased link|bar</a>
"."
```

Can anyone advise what I need to do to fix the regex to get my desired result? I'm especially confused because when I test this regex in [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com), it seems to do exactly what I think it should do:

[image]

I'm using PHP 7.4.6 on Google Chrome, with XAMPP and Apache.

Comment: Your second regex isn't wrong but it doesn't do anything because the first preg_replace has already replaced both links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the pattern that you used, you can exclude matching the `|` by adding it in the first negated character class to prevent some backtracking. The quantifier for the negated character class also does not have to be non greedy `*?` as the `]` can not be crossed at the end.

You could use 2 capture groups where the second group is in an optional part and check for the presence of group 2 using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
\[([^][|]+)(?:\|([^][]+))?]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match `[`
- `([^][|]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except `[` `]` and `|`
- `(?:\|([^][]+))?` Optional non capture group matching `|` and capture any char except the listed in **group 2**
- `]` Match closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P5CVHS/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/eEiCQ)

```
$pattern = "/\[([^][|]+)(?:\|([^][]+))?\]/";
$s = "This is an example definition. Here is a link to [foo]. This is an [aliased link|bar].";
$s = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match){
    $template = '<a href="%s">%s</a>';
    return sprintf($template, array_key_exists(2, $match) ? $match[2] : $match[1], $match[1]);
}, $s);

echo $s;
```

Output

```
This is an example definition. Here is a link to <a href="foo">foo</a>. This is an <a href="bar">aliased link</a>.
```

Comment: That's fantastic, the answer works perfectly, thank you! Just one question - why do you use greedy matches for the two capture groups, i.e. `+` instead of `+?`? I always thought it was more performant to use lazy matches, especially as the capture groups in question will still capture everything until they reach a `]` character in this case.

Comment: @Lou when you use a lazy match, there will be [backtracking](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#helpful). You don't have to use a lazy quantifier in this case, as you can use a greedy quantifier that can not cross matching the `]`

Comment: Ah okay, so `+` would actually perform *better* than `+?`, potentially?

Comment: @Lou In this case it does, but for example in this scenario where you want to match `qq` and you can not use a negated character class `[^q]` (or else you would not get to the qq because you can not pass the first `q` using that) depending on the length of the string a non greedy match would have less steps according to the regex101 tool as it is located earlier in the string. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/bajmuO/1) vs [this](https://regex101.com/r/FZhHZ1/1) and with a shorter string [this](https://regex101.com/r/4AJSU2/1) vs [this](https://regex101.com/r/lqVK5o/1)